# need to programmatically jump to another page on my site

Tags: php, javascript, header, alert

I have tried using header() to programmatically take the user to a different page
in my site after they see then dismiss an alert() box, but it's not doing what I need.

I need to:

1) have a javascript alert() echoed to the browser

2) then after the alert() box is dismissed, I need to jump to another page

3) saying 'use ajax' won't help me here as I've got a full plate just coming to grips with php,
   mysql, html5 and javascript.  Plate is full, ajax -> ***later***.

In the code below I never see the alert() -- my browser just immediately shows me shimmyLogin.php.

If I comment out the 'header()' call, then I see my alert() just fine -- but then I'm not 
doing what I need to do after the alert(), which is to programmatically take my user to shimmyLogin.php.

I'm pretty sure I know why this is happening but my question is -- is there a way to

1) pop up an alert() box

2) then after the user dismisses the alert(), I can then do a ***header()*** (or some other way)
   to jump to my other page shimmyLogin.php?

I'm really new to programmatically navigating the pages of a site and I'm aware of ***header()***
but obviously it will not work here for the 2 things I need to do above.

Here's the code:

```
if(showAlertBox("Unexpected error! "))
{
     header('Location: http://localhost/shimmyDooHah/shimmyLogin.php');
}
```

where showAlertBox is just:

```
function showAlertBox($messageToDisplay)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
        . 'alert("' . $messageToDisplay . '")</script>';

    return true;
}
```

Comment: For future reference, `header()` is only useful before you send the browser any actual output. [More on that here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). You are best off using javascript's `window.location` property for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showAlertBox() - you need to add after the alert("bla-bla"); this line:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

It will take the user to the url you will put there.

Comment: Thanks Ido, I was not aware of the window.location possibility at all, I plugged it in and it works GREAT!  Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Redirect in Javascript:

```
alert('Alert message here.');
window.location = 'http://example.com/otherpage';
```

BTW, have you maybe thought about a better way of displaying messages that doesn't use Javascript?

Comment: Thanks deceze,  I gave you a +1 up arrow, I really appreciate that you took some time to help me here -- thank you!